# Porting project from Eclipse to Android Studio changes style of buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-styles

I have switched from Eclipse to Android Studio. Since an import of my Eclipse-Project didn't work, I created a new project in Android Studio and copied the files one after the other. I got the project to work but now I am facing some strange behaviour.
On an XperiaZ with Android 5.0.2 the text of my buttons is written in uppercase letters (it isn't like this if I build the project in Eclipse). If I install the application on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4.2 the layout gets very strange. I have some buttons which I colour on my onCreate-method by using

```
 myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN,
            PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This works fine on the XperiaZ as well as on the S4 if I build the project with Eclipse, but if I build the project with Android Studio, the buttons are grey on the S4. On the XperiaZ they are coloured. If I press the button, the correct colour is set for short time but then disappears again (note that I also change the colour in the onClick-method.

I already tried different styles, but it didn't help. Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour, or an idea what I could try to fix this problem?

Comment: *On an XperiaZ with Android 5.0.2 the text of my buttons is written in uppercase letters (it isn't like this if I build the project in Eclipse).*  yes, it was ... normal Android 5+ behaviour .... any chanches that you are using appcompat library?

Comment: This sounds like a theming issue - uppercased-text grey buttons is suspiciously like the default material theme. Do you have any theme information set in your manifest or layouts?

Comment: In my manifest I have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`
In the styles.xml `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. The problem was I used an Appcompat theme. I had to use it because my Activity was extending `AppCompatActivity` (this was set by default when I created the project). I had to change it to `myActivity extends Activity` so I could use a "normal" android Theme.
I just don't know why it did work with Eclipse and with the XperiaZ...

Thanks to @Selvin and @adelphus for the hints in the right direction.